# ffmpeg and creating a single image made up of a grid of thumbnails from a video

Tags: ffmpeg

Ffmpeg is incredibly powerful but complex tool. I want to create a single image file made up of rows & columns containing still-images (thumbnails) from a video file.

The most difficult but critically important function is the thumbnails MUST be evenly distributed from the video.  For example, if the video is 60 seconds long, and the grid is 4x4 (16 thumbnails), the interval between each thumbnail is 60/16 (3.7 seconds).

Another example.  If the video is 10 minutes long, and the desired grid is 7 rows & 8 columns, the interval must be 600/7*8 (10.7 seconds).

Additional requirements (nice, but not essential):

- The image dimensions should be able to be adjusted in the code e.g. 1920 pixels wide, 900 pixels high
- A time stamp written on each thumbnail (hh:mm:ss)

An example showing all requirements met (using a commercial program) is here >
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gz3S.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/49259648/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259648/how-to-generate-tile-with-video-thumbnails-with-right-timecode

Answer (score 0):

I created a script, needs also **imagemagick**.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

directory="/tmp/your/path"
mkdir -p "$directory"

length="$(ffprobe -i "$1" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv='p=0')"
image_count="$( echo "${length}/3.75" | bc -l )"
length="${length%.*}"
image_count="${image_count%.*}"

for (( i=0; i<$image_count ; i++ )); do
    time=$(echo "${i} * 3.75" | bc -l)
    timestamp=$(date -u -d "@${time}" "+%H:%M:%S")
    ffmpeg -y -i "$1" -ss "$timestamp" -vframes 1 -vcodec png -an -y "${directory}/${timestamp}.png"
    mogrify -font helvetica -fill red -pointsize 100 -draw "text 50,50 '${timestamp}'" "${directory}/${timestamp}.png"
done
montage "${directory}/*" -geometry +10+10 grid.png
```

It takes some time to run this script, but it also adds timestamp to every image.

```sh
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -frames 1 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,1000)),scale=-1:240,tile=3x2" out.png
```

This one a loot faster
Check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/874042/how-to-make-screenshot-gallery-from-command-line

Comment: Thanks Zadca, I'm in the process of using your solution (the one with the FOR loop & timestamp on thumbs) to write my own in PowerShell.  I'm using Windows11 (I probably should have specified that!).  I'm not really a programmer but I know enough to re-write your solution in Windows PowerShell and will try not to use any ImageMagic, just pure Ffmpeg.  When I've got it working I will post my solution. Thanks.
Edit:  Question - What is the purpose of the constant '3.75' that appears twice in your script?  "Video length}/3.75" - why 3.75? Curious ...

Comment: @CandyFeng Just divided 60/16. I wasn't really sure how much images you wanted in the 10min clip.